# What's the correct way to submit a single element in a list when each of them has a separate submit button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an event page which contains a list of participants. From there users can be invited to that event by opening a modal view containing a user list. Users are shown in the same modal with each having an 'Invite'(submit) button next to them. How can I let the controller action know which user is invited?
From what I could find, creating a form for each list element is bad and in addition displays warnings, but if I create a form element on top of the 'foreach', I then need to somehow find which user to submit.
Also thought about appending incrementing numbers to each of submit button name, but I still need to somehow map them to 'their' users.
Along with the invited user id, controller post action also needs to receive the event id.
Here's the code:

```
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Select user</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
<form id="eventMemberForm" method="post" class="col-sm-6 custom-close" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="completed" data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("SendInvitation", "Sports")">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Invitation.FkEvent" value="@Model.Event.EventId" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="Invitation.EventInvitationId" />

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class="form-control p-2 mb-2" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
                    <h4 class="align-content-center">Users</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="w-100">
                            <tbody id="myField">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="d-flex">
                                            <div> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text) </div>
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Invitation.FkUser" value="@item.Value" />
                                            <div class="ml-auto">
                                                <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Invite" class="btn btn-success" />
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ++i;
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
            var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $("#myField tr").filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
            });
        });
    });

    completed = () => {
        alert("User invited");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: What is bad with creating a form for each list element? Another solution is to create one overall form have checkbox for each participant and one submit button for the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jquery ajax` to pass the parameters you need, through the click event, get the corresponding value of the control needed next to the current button.

By adding the `name` attribute to the submit button, and then triggered in jquery.

And add the `id` to the div that stores the Text value of User to facilitate finding the corresponding value in jquery.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function () {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#myField tr").filter(function () {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
            $("[name=submitBtn]").click(function () {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                var obj = {
                    myUser: {
                        Text: $($(this).parent().siblings()[0]).text(),
                        Value: $($(this).parent().siblings()[1]).val()
                    },
                    eventId: $("#Invitation_FkEvent").val()
                };



                $.ajax({
                    url: $("#eventMemberForm").attr("data-ajax-url"),
                    method: 'post',
                    data: obj,
                })
            });
        });
        completed = () => {
            alert("User invited");
        };
    </script>
}
<h1>Index</h1>
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Select user</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <form id="eventMemberForm" method="post" class="col-sm-6 custom-close" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-complete="completed" data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("SendInvitation", "Sports")">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Invitation.FkEvent" value="@Model.Event.EventId" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Invitation.EventInvitationId" />



                <div class="modal-body">
                    <input class="form-control p-2 mb-2" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
                    <h4 class="align-content-center">Users</h4>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <table class="w-100">
                            <tbody id="myField">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Users)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="d-flex">
                                            <div id="textValue"> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Text) </div>
                                            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Invitation.FkUser" value="@item.Value" />
                                            <div class="ml-auto">
                                                <input id="btnSave" type="submit" value="Invite" class="btn btn-success" name="submitBtn"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    ++i;
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult SendInvitation(User myUser, string eventId)
        {
            //do what you want
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, worked fine with some minimal changes.